# Google Data Studio: Can I display the current date range a user is running a report at on screen in a text box?

Tags: looker-studio

I want to clarify very clearly in a Data Studio report what the date range is that the report is currently running over.

So I want to add a text box up at the top of the screen to display this.
Is this possible?

From what I understand text labels can't display anything dynamically.  Is it possible to do this with a function using the 'scorecard' data chart type or something similar ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't make a label dynamic.  However, you can make a table look like a label.

If you remove everything from a table (row numbers, title, border, colors, etc) it will look like a label with the ability to update dynamically.  You can also use this trick to display dynamic images.

After this, just add any date field you already have as a metric, using functions `MIN` or `MAX` accordingly.

[image: Example picture of dynamic labels]

Step-by-step to turn a table into a dynamic label:

1. Disable `Show header`
2. Cell table color: `Transparent`
3. Odd/Even row color: `Transparent`
4. Disable `Row numbers`
5. Disable `Show pagination`
6. Background color: `Transparent`
7. Border color: `Transparent`
8. Chart header: `Do not show`

I made a public dashboard to illustrate the results:

- [Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/5f8a2843-d1a9-460f-a913-6cf3be4b8ea7)
- [Data Source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BXTjsUw0bvcRmm8UiNEZ8izmaZMfxborhIg2-NgO3ts/edit#gid=0)

Comment: Amazing thanks @Diego.   One tiny question; in the screenshot above you have a comma in the date after the number for the day of the month.  That isn't in your demo.  How do I achieve that, maybe add the rd/st etc ?

Comment: Actually, when I open the dashboard I see exactly what in the screenshot. Google dates follows your current locale (the one set in your Google Account). My account is using "English (United States)". So if your locale is different (other language/country), you may see different results. But if you want a formatted date, you can always create a new field and use the `FORMAT_DATETIME` function (see https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334).

Comment: Thank you so much this is the answer that I was looking for good thing you have one here and also a follow up on the gsheet for the data source how can we make it dynamic instead of typing the date and drag and drop all the way down?

Comment: @ErrolBoneo Your inquiry was not clear for me. Don't you prefer to formulate it better as a new question?

Comment: What a great solution. I just want to point out that you don't even need to use a MIN and MAX formula. Just set the first table to be ordered by date ascending , and the second by date descending and then set the number of rows on both to be 1.